# Parsing URL query string into next page

Tags: php

I have created a multi langual website.
If the visitor chooses the German language then will get the URL the query string: /?lang=de

But if the visitor chooses a new page than he will get the default language and not German.

Is there a way to add the query string into the next page and so on?

Many thanks!

Comment: and what have you tried before asking SO?

Comment: I have tried using '$_SESSION' and '$_GET'

Comment: As someone who oversaw the development of a multi-lingual website, I can tell you that simple $_GET requests from page to page will not work. You will need some kind of CMS that controls all your pages and keeps track of what language the user currently wants.

Comment: @RussJ a CMS isn't necessary. Just a session value to set a language and set text accordingly

Comment: @treyBake I disagree with you. How can you share a page in a specific language if you are using sessions?

Comment: @Cid set language to an id, switch statement that value and phrase relevant language file (similar to magento xml translation)

Comment: @treyBake I meant, how can you copy and paste an URL in a specific language if you are using session ?

Comment: @Cid ah in that case, get param to set the session on init load then go from there

Comment: I Use the following 'onclick' command to switch the language. I think here I have to change something:
        
`<a href="index?lang=nl" <?php if($lang == 'nl'){?> <?php } ?>>Dutch</a>
<a href="index?lang=de" <?php if($lang == 'de'){?> <?php } ?>>German</a>`

Comment: @treyBake if you send that url to a friend, he won't have the session that sets the language

Comment: @cid no, that's why you check the url, if user shares and if session Isset to language, append get var for that language, then if Isset get language, set language for that user